# Javascript `fetch` and Shibboleth CORS error

Tags: javascript, fetch, shibboleth

I am developing an app and just moved it behind a Shibboleth SSO running on Apache. Static pages behind Shibboleth work as expected, but when I use `fetch("test.html")` I get a CORS error. I have tried this with jQuery's `$.ajax` command, and I do not get the CORS error.

What is missing from the `fetch` command that jQuery fixes for me?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by relative url? Unless you just mean protocol relative, a relative url would be same origin and therefore not subject to CORS policy.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and **quote** the error message, don't just vaguely describe it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `jQuery.ajax` and `fetch` differ in that `fetch` does not send credentials by default. `fetch("test.html", { credentials: "same-origin" })` avoids the CORS error.